# Swagger The type 'addressFamily' already contains a definition for '_6'

Tags: swagger, nswagstudio

Every time I use NSwagStudio to generate a new NSwagProxy.cs file I have the above error.  I have a duplicate of _6 and _7.  My development team always has to scroll through the file to delete these two extra lines.  The duplicates are also in the swagger UI Schema.  I'm not sure where this schema is being pulled from.  I've seen this in several other peoples swagger UI's. but can't find any solutions to this problem.  Any insight would be appreciated.  Thanks!

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "10.1.5.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v12.0.0.0)")]
public enum AddressFamily
{
    _0 = 0,

    _1 = 1,

    _2 = 2,

    _3 = 3,

    _4 = 4,

    _5 = 5,

    _6 = 6,

    _6 = 6,

    _7 = 7,

    _7 = 7,

    _8 = 8,

    _9 = 9,

    _10 = 10,

    _11 = 11,

    _12 = 12,

    _13 = 13,

    _14 = 14,

    _15 = 15,

    _16 = 16,

    _17 = 17,

    _18 = 18,

    _19 = 19,

    _21 = 21,

    _22 = 22,

    _23 = 23,

    _24 = 24,

    _25 = 25,

    _26 = 26,

    _28 = 28,

    _29 = 29,

    _65536 = 65536,

    _65537 = 65537,

    __1 = -1,

}
```

NSwagProject.nswag file below

```
    {
  "runtime": "NetCore30",
  "defaultVariables": null,
  "documentGenerator": {
    "fromDocument": {
      "url": "https://localhost:44372/swagger/v1/swagger.json",
      "output": null
    }
  },
  "codeGenerators": {
    "openApiToCSharpClient": {
      "clientBaseClass": null,
      "configurationClass": null,
      "generateClientClasses": false,
      "generateClientInterfaces": false,
      "injectHttpClient": true,
      "disposeHttpClient": true,
      "protectedMethods": [],
      "generateExceptionClasses": false,
      "exceptionClass": "ApiException",
      "wrapDtoExceptions": true,
      "useHttpClientCreationMethod": false,
      "httpClientType": "System.Net.Http.HttpClient",
      "useHttpRequestMessageCreationMethod": false,
      "useBaseUrl": true,
      "generateBaseUrlProperty": true,
      "generateSyncMethods": false,
      "exposeJsonSerializerSettings": false,
      "clientClassAccessModifier": "public",
      "typeAccessModifier": "public",
      "generateContractsOutput": false,
      "contractsNamespace": null,
      "contractsOutputFilePath": null,
      "parameterDateTimeFormat": "s",
      "parameterDateFormat": "yyyy-MM-dd",
      "generateUpdateJsonSerializerSettingsMethod": true,
      "serializeTypeInformation": false,
      "queryNullValue": "",
      "className": "{controller}Client",
      "operationGenerationMode": "MultipleClientsFromOperationId",
      "additionalNamespaceUsages": [],
      "additionalContractNamespaceUsages": [],
      "generateOptionalParameters": false,
      "generateJsonMethods": false,
      "enforceFlagEnums": false,
      "parameterArrayType": "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable",
      "parameterDictionaryType": "System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary",
      "responseArrayType": "System.Collections.Generic.ICollection",
      "responseDictionaryType": "System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary",
      "wrapResponses": false,
      "wrapResponseMethods": [],
      "generateResponseClasses": true,
      "responseClass": "SwaggerResponse",
      "namespace": "Fms.Services.ServiceAgent.AppSupportApi",
      "requiredPropertiesMustBeDefined": true,
      "dateType": "System.DateTimeOffset",
      "jsonConverters": null,
      "anyType": "object",
      "dateTimeType": "System.DateTime",
      "timeType": "System.TimeSpan",
      "timeSpanType": "System.TimeSpan",
      "arrayType": "System.Collections.Generic.ICollection",
      "arrayInstanceType": "System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection",
      "dictionaryType": "System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary",
      "dictionaryInstanceType": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary",
      "arrayBaseType": "System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection",
      "dictionaryBaseType": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary",
      "classStyle": "Poco",
      "generateDefaultValues": true,
      "generateDataAnnotations": true,
      "excludedTypeNames": [],
      "excludedParameterNames": [],
      "handleReferences": false,
      "generateImmutableArrayProperties": false,
      "generateImmutableDictionaryProperties": false,
      "jsonSerializerSettingsTransformationMethod": null,
      "inlineNamedArrays": false,
      "inlineNamedDictionaries": false,
      "inlineNamedTuples": true,
      "inlineNamedAny": false,
      "generateDtoTypes": true,
      "generateOptionalPropertiesAsNullable": false,
      "templateDirectory": null,
      "typeNameGeneratorType": null,
      "propertyNameGeneratorType": null,
      "enumNameGeneratorType": null,
      "serviceHost": null,
      "serviceSchemes": null,
      "output": null
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the original code from which this enum is generated?

Comment: @Helen, is this what you meant or did you want the entire project?

Answer (score 0):

We have the same issue, whenever we generate the c# code, a lot of the attributes have these duplicated enums, so the code doesn't compile.

What we found out was that our Controllers were returning a custom class that contained a property with type Exception. Swashbuckle is trying to serialize the Exception property but has difficulty with it. Adding [JsonIgnore] before the property solved our issue.